# How to create a coconut using particles

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm making a dry coconut with the help of particles systems. I tried to create a strand along the surface, but the hair is still emitted from the surface. Is there an addon to do this? How can I make the particles look like a coconut? How to wrap them around the base mesh?

[image]

[image]

**Reference image**

[image]

How can I achieve the reference image effect on my mesh? Any other suggestion or help? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets start with a few hairs and go into Particle Edit Mode. Use the comb brush to move shape them along the surface. Make sure to include some hairs that don't move the same direction as the others or it will look too boring.
I played with the material settings a bit and used a slight colour variation from root to tip which is controlled by the thickness.

[image]

[image]

I will then add at least one other particle system, so that we can control the few brighter ones separately from the darker base. By combining three systems on top of each other I got the result above.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(Could use some more tweaking but for demonstration purposes...)
[image]

Comment: can u plz send me the file so i go through it. Thanks

Comment: I attached the .blend file